# How to use JS functions/variables defined in another file?

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Currently I have a file `src/index.re`. I also have a file `src/util.js` which defines some helper functions I’d like to use. How do I use those functions in `src/index.re`?

Comment: Have you tried the module syntax? You can find the docs here: https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/import-export.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil said in the comments, you'll want to use the [`bs.module` attribute](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/import-export.html).

Here's a concrete example:

```
[@bs.module "./util"] external helper : string => int = "";
```

This says that `helper` is a function in `./util.js` that takes a `string` and returns an `int`. You can now use it as an ordinary function:

```
let n : int = helper("hello");
```